# Problems with display in Webkit

Tags: css, webkit, css-tables

I am using display: table and table-cell divs (which are placed in display:table div) to create layout for my site. I only have 2 cells (first is sidebar and second is main content). It is working great in firefox but in chrome and other webkit browsers content of sidebar simply moves under main content. Column layout works good but it looks like webkit is putting my sidebar content in second row and main content in first row. I have also tried wraping divs (sidebar and main) aleso inside table-row div but it isnt working.
It looks like this in firefox:
[image: Firefox]

And it looks like this in Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

any solution to this?

Comment: Attaching some of your css would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is usually vertical aligning, use

```
vertical-align: top;
```

for the elements that render with `display: table-cell`, i.e. your sidebar perhaps. Then its content will start flowing from the top.